# How to make more than one Embed with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am having a problem where when I make more than one Embed on Discord.py, the first command doesn't respond but the second one does.

**Here's my code:**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game('private'))
    print('bot is online')
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.kade'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Kade Engine Download", description="Downloads for Kade Engine 1.8", color=0x2C93FA)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Kade Engine Installation", value="https://github.com/KadeDev/Kade-Engine/releases/tag/1.8", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Kade Engine Source (Recommended for Mod Makers)", value="https://github.com/KadeDev/Kade-Engine", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.week'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="How to make a week", description="How to make a week", color=0x2C93FA)
        embedVar.add_field(name="test", value="test", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="test", value="test", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)


client.run('WONT SHOW BOT TOKEN')
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating an `on_message()` event you shouldn't create it multiple times. Create one and make multiple `if/elif` statements or use [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#commands) which give you more capabilities.

**Your fixed code with **`on_message()`** (delete both `on_message` events and replace with):**

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.kade'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Kade Engine Download", description="Downloads for Kade Engine 1.8", color=0x2C93FA)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Kade Engine Installation", value="https://github.com/KadeDev/Kade-Engine/releases/tag/1.8", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Kade Engine Source (Recommended for Mod Makers)", value="https://github.com/KadeDev/Kade-Engine", inline=False) 
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
    
    elif message.content.startswith('.week'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="How to make a week", description="How to make a week", color=0x2C93FA)
        embedVar.add_field(name="test", value="test", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="test", value="test", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

**or use commands (recommended):**

```py
@client.command()
async def kade(ctx):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Kade Engine Download", description="Downloads for Kade Engine 1.8", color=0x2C93FA)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Kade Engine Installation", value="https://github.com/KadeDev/Kade-Engine/releases/tag/1.8", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Kade Engine Source (Recommended for Mod Makers)", value="https://github.com/KadeDev/Kade-Engine", inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@client.command()
async def week(ctx):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="How to make a week", description="How to make a week", color=0x2C93FA)
    embedVar.add_field(name="test", value="test", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="test", value="test", inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: I would just like to add to this answer that if you do end up using the commands extension, be cautious of the `on_message` event. Whenever you have both commands and an `on_message` event, you need to make sure that you process the related commands first using `await client.process_commands(message)`.

Comment: Thank you so much Riven for this I was brain blocked for so long, I'm a beginner so this really helps. Once again Thank you.